# Twig / Grav modular get index

Tags: twig, grav

Can i get the index from the outer loop or pass it in somehow to an inner module?

list.html.twig

```
<ul>
    {% for module in page.collection %}
        <li>
            {{ module.content }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

service.html.twig

```
<h2>{{ loop.index }} </h2>
```

[image]

*Edit*

I still can't figure this out. Is it possible to get the index of current module inside its twig template based on the index at which it appears in its order? So Communications strategy should be index 2 ... or 1 if 0 base.

Comment: How and where do you include `modular`?

Comment: i'm looping over the collection which is a list of modules that belong to the page

Comment: So you are doing something like `{% for p in collection %}{% include "modular.html.twig" %}{% endfor %}`? If this is the case then `loop.index` is already known inside `modular`

Comment: nope, the {{ p.content }} pulls in the grav modular component

Comment: Which im now starting to think if im including it like that then it must already be processed and be a plain string so maybe what im trying to do can't be done this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out a workaround.

You can include a modular like this instead

```
<ul>
    {% for module in page.collection %}
        <li>
            {% include module.template ~ '.html.twig' with {page: module} %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It probably has a slight performance hit doing it this way as i believe you're rendering the partial for a second time but it gives you complete access to the outer scope.

***Edit***

This functionality was actually missing from the page object so i added it in and it can be used as of v1.3.3

https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/theme-vars#currentposition